# Combining multiple postgres scripts in one file

Tags: postgresql

I have two files that both work fine when executing them in Postgres.

**File 1**

```
CREATE TABLE ContractStatusEnum (
    id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    description         VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);
```

**File 2*

```
DO $$ BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ContractStatusEnum WHERE id = 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO ContractStatusEnum (id, description) VALUES
        (1, 'Ordered'),
        (2, 'Active'),
        (3, 'Stopped'),
        (4, 'Canceled'),
        (10, 'Inactive');
    END IF;
END $$
```

However, if I just put them together in one file, it fails with

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DO"
>   LINE 6:     DO $$ BEGIN

On MS SQL I can solve this by creating a new context by putting a `GO` statement between two scripts. Any clue how to do it in Postgres 9?

Comment: `Do` is only valid in pgplsql. You can omit the do. Just concatenate the fragments (possibly each statement terminated by a semicolon. The `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax is invalid: use a WHERE clause instead.

Comment: The `IF NOT EXISTS` statement runs fine when I execute the second file in postgres without concatenating. Should I run the complete script in pgplsql?

Comment: Yes, you can even redirect stdin for psql and use a pipe or '<' to submit a whole script file. Ehh: no, you don't need pgplsql just to submit sql code. just the psql "terminal" executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate your `DO` block with a semicolon.

The following works for me:

```
DO $$ BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ContractStatusEnum WHERE id = 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO ContractStatusEnum (id, description) VALUES
        (1, 'Ordered'),
        (2, 'Active'),
        (3, 'Stopped'),
        (4, 'Canceled'),
        (10, 'Inactive');
    END IF;
END $$
;
```

I saved the statements in f1.sql (create table) and f2.sql (do block):

```
psql (9.1.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \i f1.sql
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> \i f2.sql
DO
postgres=>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the fragments. No / or `GO` is needed. (in interactive mode for psql a \g *may* be needed)

```
CREATE TABLE ContractStatusEnum (
    id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    description         VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);

    -- File 2

 INSERT INTO ContractStatusEnum (id, description) VALUES 
     (1, 'Ordered'),
     (2, 'Active'),
     (3, 'Stopped'),
     (4, 'Canceled'),
     (10, 'Inactive')
  ;
```

EDIT: removed the WHERE clause (it is not even valid here) The PK constraint on the table will avoid multiple initialisations anyway.

Another way of concatenation is by means of *inclusion*. You can create a "master" script, and include the fragments from there. Comes in handy when you want to "comment-out" whole portions.

```
-- Master script.

\i tables_create.sql
\i procedures_and_functions.sql
\i populate_the_tables.sql
\i do_some_checks.sql

-- EOF
```

Comment: I understand I can get rid of it by omitting the pgplsql, but I have more complicated scripts that require running in that mode.

Comment: I don't think pgplsql is valid outside procedures/functions. I would certainly not want it.

Comment: @wildplasser: it is certainly valid inside a `DO` block

Comment: Oops. I stand corrected. I never use it; the INSERT will fail because of the PK constraint. (this appears to be a table creation+initialisation script)